# LSTM predict one result at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I trying to predict a single result from my `LSTM` model

my model has `n_features = 32` and `time_step = 100` with following code

```
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer( input_shape=(time_step , n_features)), 
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)]
)
```

I trained my model using generator

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(x_feature,y_target,length=time_step ,batch_size = 128)
```

When I try to predict my model using test dataset with shape of `(2,32)`, which has 2 rows and 32 features.

(I'm planning to get 2 predictions from my model)

I have the following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. 
Full shape received: [None, 32]
```

I understand this because my test dataset has shape of `[None,32]`, but how can I reshape it, so that it becomes shape of `(100,32)`

I tried to reshape using

```
x_feature.reshape(-1,100,36)
model.predict(x_feature)
```

However it shows

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 64 into shape (100,36)
```

How can I deal with such reshape problem, when my input shape of model is `100,36` but test dataset has shape of `2,36` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Keras` model always expects `inputs` to have shape `(batch_size, time_steps, n_features)` in the case of `LSTM` layers. When you train, it works because you train on multiple examples, i.e., with a fixed batch size. However, when you predict, and you are using *one* example, you **should** add a batch dimension for it to work. Let us say your single example `x` has shape `(time_steps,n_features)`, you should use:

```
x = numpy.expand_dims(x, 0)
```

which converts your `x` to have a shape of `(1, time_steps, n_features)` and the model would work as if the inputs have a batch size of *1*. Now if you call

```
output = model.predict(x)
```

your output would be a list with one element. So `output[0]` would be the prediction for the your original *x*.

The error you mentioned is caused because you are not adding the batch dimension and hence the model complains that it gets an input with ndim=2 instead of 3. The modifications suggested above will resolve the error, however it will still not work for the problem you are trying to solve because you are training the model with time_steps of 100 and features of 32. So it will only work if your test example has that many time steps.