# How to use Keras' LSTM to predict at a single timestamp

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I currently have a trained LSTM model that I'm using to model a column in Dataframe A. I have all of the training and validation data at my disposal, but I'm writing a method that iterates over Dataframe A sequentially and only has access to the trained LSTM model and the data up until the current point of iteration. I'm also not needing the prediction for every single column, so being able to spit out my model's prediction at any given timestamp would be very helpful for my purposes. My problem is simply that I do not understand how to do this. I checked out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782903/lstm-predict-one-result-at-a-time) and followed it exactly.

```
x = input_data.iloc[0:10]
x = np.expand_dims(x,0)
output = model.predict(x)
```

My time_step is 10, so I simply select the first ten datapoints to try to predict the next (or at least this is how I understand it, please correct me if I'm wrong), modify its shape, then predict from this. This outputs something completely different from my training data. Any insights?

Updated for more info: The shape of the data that I used for training and validation is (2774188, 31). When I train it, I use

```
train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train, y_train, length=sequence_length, batch_size=64)
```

and the structure of my model is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(sequence_length, X_train.shape[1])))  # First LSTM layer
model.add(Dense(1))  # Number of output nodes = number of response variables
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
```

When I run the code in the original post, my output is simply [[-0.110392]] which raises red flags for me, mainly because the maximum prediction I obtained across all the training/validation data is 0.04. I expected something closer to 0.002 as my output. I want to clarify that I am new to both Keras / LSTM models and have rough understanding of both but mainly am just trying to make sure my problem isn't something I'm forgetting in the setup.

Comment: Please add additional code and information. What shape is your data/your output? What did you expect?

Comment: Updated. Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide. Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Why does `[[-0.110392]]` raise a red flag for you? What target data did you expect? Could it be that the 0.04 in your training was the loss value from the mse loss? Normally TensorFlow does not show absolute prediction values during training.

Comment: It raises a red flag because 1. I am predicting a value already determined in the training data and has a significant difference.  2. It is significantly larger than any prediction prior. 3. Cannot be the MSE loss because plotting the predictions against the actual data gives me confidence that the predictions are correct and represent what I want. 

I rescaled the data back and repeatedly get the same answer. Could it just be that LSTM isn't designed for this single-example prediction despite the fact that I'm feeding it the prior data?

Comment: Just because the data point was in the training set doesn't mean the model has to be capable to perfectly predict it. Can you add the prediction in training for comparison? Or just the `.fit` output of the training? And if you compared the prediction against the data and it seems correct, what is the problem? Or was it another prediction that you compared? In general, LSTM is exactly designed for single (or multi) step prediction with a window for prior data. If the data makes sense and the model fits the data, it should handle the prediction.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like I'm not being clear in my responses; I completely agree with what you said. My main concern is that consistently throughout the values I have checked, there are discrepancies between what the model predicts during training and what I am trying to have it replicate later. In this case, the model output -0.11 on an example that had a prediction of -0.002 during training. As in, there is a significant difference between what it predicts during training and what I am trying to replicate. My model's predictions seem correct except when I try to replicate them as single examples.

Comment: That's strange, the results in the last training epoch and the prediction should be relatively close. Can you add the code part where you compare training and results?